# On a form with a number of radio buttons, ( yes or no ) how do I get the row( TR) to dynamically change color according to choice?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a checklist if you will, where when a radio button is selected ( yes or no ) I'd like the row (TR) to  dynamically change. How can I do this? 
SP2010

Comment: How do you want the TR to change?

Comment: Hello, I mentioned I'd like it to change color.
i.e. If yes = row is green, if no the color is red...

Comment: You can use calculated column to show different color according to condition in list.

Comment: Hello dikesh will the background color refresh and change as soon as I click a radio button using calculated columns?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you look at jQuery which can be used to highlight a row or cell using an event like onclick.

Try starting with this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703710/changing-the-color-of-a-clicked-table-row-using-jquery